# Google Cloud Engine: I've attached 15 certificates(the maximum allowed) to a load balancer. How do I scale from there?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, devops, kubernetes-ingress

I generate certificates using LetsEncrypt for each domain that points their CNAME/A-Record to my IP/Domain. Secrets are then generated from them specified in the "tls" section of my ingress config.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: great-site
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'true'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: 'great-site-production'
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: domain.one-2019-09-10
    - secretName: domain.two-2019-09-10
    - secretName: domain.three-2019-09-10
    - secretName: domain.four-2019-09-10
    - secretName: domain.five-2019-09-10
    - secretName: domain.six-2019-09-11
    - secretName: domain.seven-2019-10-19
    - secretName: domain.eight-2019-10-19
    - secretName: domain.nine-2019-10-20
    - secretName: domain.ten-2019-10-21
    - secretName: domain.eleven-2019-10-22
    - secretName: domain.twelve-2019-10-23
    - secretName: domain.thirteen-2019-10-24
    - secretName: domain.fourteen-2019-10-26
    - secretName: domain.fifteen-2019-10-27
  rules:
    - host: domain.one
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.two
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.three
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.four
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081

    - host: domain.five
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
   - host: domain.six
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.seven
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.eight
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.nine
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081

    - host: domain.ten
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
- host: domain.eleven
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.twelve
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.thirteen
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
    - host: domain.fourteen
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081

    - host: domain.fifteen
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: great-site-service
              servicePort: 8081
```

15 is the maximum number of certificates one can attach to a load balancer so adding any more secrets to this doesn't work. I want to know what to do in order to scale from here and register more domains. Or if there's a better approach I could take for the whole thing.

Comment: 1) Provisioning more than a couple of certificates is not a good idea for performance. 2) Google Load Balancers support 10 certificates officially. 3) I think you either need to terminate TLS at your applications or deploy more than one cluster.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley. They seem to support 15 now. I'll look into your suggestions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [Wildcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) or [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) certificates.

With a Wildcard certificate, you can secure a theoretical unlimited number of domains.

While with a SAN certificate it's up to the CA to define a limit on the number of domains that can be secured with the certificate. For LetsEncrypt as [stated](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/):

> If you have a lot of subdomains, you may want to combine them into a single certificate, up to a limit of 100 Names per Certificate.

Further information can be found on [LetsEncrypt FAQs](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) (while the first Q was answered implicitly in the previous quote):

> **Can I get a certificate for multiple domain names (SAN certificates or
>   UCC certificates)?**
>
> Yes, the same certificate can contain several different names using the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) mechanism.
>
> **Does Let’s Encrypt issue wildcard certificates?**
>
> Yes. Wildcard issuance must be done via ACMEv2 using the DNS-01 challenge. See [this post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578) for more technical information.

You can find [here](https://www.thawte.com/resources/pdfs/Thawte_Multiuse_SSL_WP.pdf) some background on these along with certificate management considerations that might help you contemplate this issue from a more design-oriented standpoint.

For support of Wildcard and SAN certificates with GCP LB please confirm official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates). 
While for SAN certificates, as it's featured in the linked documentation

> SAN certificates are supported for HTTPS load balancing

it could be assumed that both Google-managed and self-managed certificates are being referred.

For Wildcard certificates:

> Google-managed SSL certificates do not support using wildcards.

Anyways, the use case from the original poster relates to self-managed certificates, but as pointed by a community peer, it might be nice to have this last piece of information here.

Comment: Google Load Balancers do NOT support wildcard certificates and only support one name per certificate.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not what it says [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates), can you go through that documentation and undownvote if it was you please?

Comment: Actually, you have me on this one. I was speaking for Google issued certificates and not self-managed certificates. I forgot the second case. Google-managed SSL certificates do not support using wildcards or multiple subject alternate names. Modify your answer to clarify the difference so that others know the difference.

Comment: Well, since the beginning of the question, the poster was talking about self-managed certificates but I added information according to your suggestion. Thanks